# Quotation marks in bash exec

Tags: bash, exec

I want to start an application in bash with the `exec` command. The problem is that the command to start the application uses quotation marks and and must not contain duplicate spaces.

So I tried the following code:

```sh
START_CMD="java -jar DockerProcessWrapper.jar -execute \"java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml -jar server.jar\" -shutdown stop"
exec $(echo "$START_CMD" | tr -s " ")
```

This does not work, the application throws the following error:
`org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml" is not a valid option`

I think there is a problem with the quotation marks in the command.
But if I execute the given command by myself, it works. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use an array of arguments rather than a string.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you create an example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of falling down the rabbit hole of escaping and quoting hell, use an array of arguments.

```
start_command=(java -jar DockerProcessWrapper.jar
                    -execute "java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml -jar server.jar"
                    -shutdown stop)
exec "${start_command[@]}"
```

To remove duplicate spaces from the array elements, you can use substitution parameter expansion with extglob:

```
shopt -s extglob
exec "${start_command[@]//+( )/ }"
```

Comment: That works fine, but how do I remove the duplicated spaces in the array?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated spaces? The non-quoted spaces in the array declaration are parsed away by the shell and I see no duplicate space in the quotes.

Comment: In my code later the start command will contain other variables and it's important, that there're no duplicated spaces in the start command. For that I used `$(echo "$START_CMD" | tr -s " ")`, but I don't know how to handle it with the array.

Comment: @Dominic: You can run `start_command=("${start_command[@]//+( )/ }")` under `shopt -s extglob`.